# slick slider get every image offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

How to get slick slider every image offset. As my requirement, I have using fig caption in every image right bottom. So I need image offset. Anyone help me is this possible for the slick slider.

```
<div class="your-class">
  <div>
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" />
    <div class=" img-cnt ">
      <p>Image 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><img src="images/img2.jpg" />
    <div class="img-cnt">
      <p>Image 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/img3.jpg" />
    <div class=" img-cnt ">
      <p>Image 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript ">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.your-class').slick({});
  });
</script>
```